# Does Mirror Image stack with Blur?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, spells

If you have the effects of a *[Blur](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/spells/blur.htm)* and a *[Mirror Image](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/spells/mirrorImage.htm)* spell on you at the same, do your mirror images gain the 20% miss chance of *Blur*?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

### Yep.

> The subject’s outline appears blurred, shifting and wavering. This distortion grants the subject concealment (20% miss chance).

-

> Several illusory duplicates of **you**
>
> When you and the mirror image separate, observers **can’t use vision or hearing to tell which one is you and which the image**.
>
> The figments mimic your actions, pretending to cast spells when you cast a spell, **drink potions when you drink a potion, levitate when you levitate, and so on.**

Both RAW and RAI seem to support the idea that your mirrored images would also be blurred, and enemies attacking them would have to roll any miss chances in order to hit them.  They aren't separate creatures, they are a spell effect that copies anything you do visually.  So displacement, etc, would also function for your mirrored images.

Comment: Protip: If an enemy caster casts blur AND mirror images, just close your eyes, you will have better chances of hitting him.

Comment: @ShadowKras You'll need to find out which square he occupies first. Do note, images may appear as far as 40' from the caster. What happens when you destroy middle one is probably a separate question.

Comment: FWIW, the somewhat-hated main FAQ says the same thing=)

Comment: @annoyingimp Obligatory [Rocky IV](http://www.hark.com/clips/xgctbjfvgw-i-see-three-of-him-out-there) reference.

Comment: "his spell creates a number of illusory doubles of you that inhabit your square. " Nope, all in the same square. You can find the square with your eyes open, then close them to attack.